# DataLoaders - wrapping an iterable over the Dataset means?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I am reading the official documentation of Dataloaders:

```
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html
```

And there is this sentence "DataLoader wraps an iterable around the Dataset.."

I know that dataloaders are used to iterate over the dataset but what I don't get is that what does wrapping an iterable over the dataset means? I want an insight of the theoretical point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence means that a DataLoader can be used to iterate the contents of a Dataset. For example, if you've got a Dataset of 1000 images, you can iterate certain attributes in the order that they've been stored in the Dataset and nothing else by itself. In the other hand, a DataLoader that wraps that Dataset allows you to iterate the data in batches, shuffle the data, apply functions, sample data, etc. Just checkout the Pytorch docs on [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) and you'll see all of the options included.

Comment: So, it means that a dataloader is used to iterate over the dataset's contents, in the order that they are stored in and can also be used for extra functions - shuffle etc (in case of wrapping). Am I right?

Comment: I think you almost got it. A dataloader only iterates a dataset, it does not modify it's contents. To be precise, for example, it doesn't shuffle the dataset contents, but it can iterate the contents of a dataset in a random order (not exactly the same)